# Filtering voted answers or questions by tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I often vote on answers or questions in SO. When I need to find an answer, it's very difficult to find: the votes are listed in descending order by date. If my vote was long ago, it's very hard to find it.

Is there any advanced search feature to filtering my votes by tag, or any other criteria?

I tried to find a channel in IFTTT that connects my Stack Overflow activity to Pockets, but didn't succeed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @AlonEitan when I do user:mine, I am seeing only my questions and my answers not the ones which I voted

Comment: *filtering my votes by tag, or any other criteria* - since your question is not exclusively about tag filtering, it might make sense to remove "by tags" from the question title.

Answer (score 8):

One thing you can do is favorite the Question.  Then you can search for it like you would anything else by using

```
infavorites:mine
```

To filter the results to just questions you have Favorited.

So, if you had a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) question you want to find from your favorites you would use

```
[python] infavorites:mine
```

Comment: Okay... what about the answers???

Comment: You can favorite any question: your own questions, questions you answered and even questions with no participation of you at all. So, just favorite the question with your answer and you can find it via the query mentioned above.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though. The question is about searching for posts you voted on, not posts you favorited. I shouldn't need to favorite every single post I vote on just to make it easier to find later.

Comment: I think the theory is that if you find the question, you can sort answers by votes, so the most helpful answers should then be at the top.  Of course, this breaks down if you have a different sense of what's "helpful" to that of the other voters.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me all the time!

A lot of times I have a problem and find a solution on Stack Overflow. A while later, I have the same problem, and remember that I found a solution on Stack Overflow the first time around, yet can't easily find the post that previously helped me.

#### Idea #1:

I would propose a feature request to add a search box under the votes tab on the user activity page. This search box will then only search posts you voted on, and will make it much easier to find posts that were previously helpful.

Here is a sketch of my idea:

> [image: sub search]

#### Idea #2:

If the above is not feasible, I would then suggest adding additional filters to the main search like "inupvote" and "indownvote".

Comment: Perhaps if your learned rather than pasting, you'd not need to look for the same answer again? You could find an answer the first time, and not the second? And you want someone else to write code so you don't have to improve?

Comment: @BillWoodger I am a big believer in understanding code and not just copying and pasting, so that is not the case here. I am just human and forget things every once in a while. Maybe "a few months later" is not the best time frame to use in my answer, because if it is only a few months, usually I remember the answer. Sometimes, though, the time before a problem comes up again is long enough that I don't remember the actual solution, but I still remember that I had this problem before.

Comment: @BillWoodger And yes, I could start looking from scratch to find an answer to the same problem, and that is what I would do now. Finding an answer though sometimes takes a bit of time, since you need to search until you find a page that has an answer that works for your specific problem. If I know I already have the page I want in my list of votes, it would be much simpler and faster to find the answer if I was just searching that list. It's basically just searching in a pre-filtered list of SO posts that I previously found helpful instead of doing a Google search that searches everything.